# How to get the predicted values in training data set for Least Squares Support Vector Regression

Tags: regression, svm, least-squares

I would like to make a prediction by using Least Squares Support Vector Machine for Regression, which is proposed by Suykens et al. I am using LS-SVMlab, which you can find the MATLAB toolbox [here](http://www.esat.kuleuven.be/sista/lssvmlab/). Let's consider I have an independent variable X and a dependent variable Y, that both are simulated. I am following the instructions in the tutorial.

> >>X = linspace(-1,1,50)’;
>   >>Y = (15*(X.^2-1).^2.*X.^4).*exp(-X)+normrnd(0,0.1,length(X),1);
>   >>type = ’function estimation’;
>   >>[gam,sig2] = tunelssvm({X,Y,type,[], [],’RBF_kernel’},’simplex’,...’leaveoneoutlssvm’,’mse’});
>   >>[alpha,b] = trainlssvm({X,Y,type,gam,sig2,’RBF_kernel’});
>   >>plotlssvm({X,Y,type,gam,sig2,’RBF_kernel’},{alpha,b});

The code above finds the best parameters using simplex method and leave-one-out cross validation and trains the model and give me alphas (support vector values for all the data points in the training set) and b coefficients. However, it does not give me the predictions of the variable Y. It only draws the plot. In some articles, I saw plots like the one below,
[image]

As I said before, the LS-SVM toolbox does not give me the predicted values of Y, it only draws the plot but no values in the workspace. How can I get these values and draw a graph of predicted values together with actual values?

There is one solution that I think of. By using X values in the training set, I re-run the model and get the prediction of values Y by using `simlssvm` command but it does not seem reasonable to me. Any solution that you can offer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you have answered your own question. The only way to obtain the prediction for the training points in LS-SVMLab is by simulating the training points after training your model.

Comment: Much obliged! There's nothing left to do, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

[yp,alpha,b,gam,sig2,model] = lssvm(x,y,'f')

when u use this function yp is the predicted value